# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'routeConfig' of null" on Karma-Jasmine for Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'routeConfig' of null"

I'm importing "RouterTestingModule", but seems some something is not right,not sure what the problem is.

Anyone facing this problem?

**Code**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { MyService } from '../services/my-service/my.service';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

  // mock the service
  class MockMyService extends MyService {
    // mock everything used by the component
  };

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ MyComponent ],
      providers: [{
        provide: MyService,
        useClass: MockMyService
      }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**MyComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-action-bar",
  templateUrl: "./action-bar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./action-bar.component.css"]
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  buttons: ActionBarButton[];
  messages: string[] = [];
  componentId: number;

  constructor(
    private myService: MyService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.componentId = (this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.routeConfig
      .data as PageViewModel).Id;
    this.buttons = new Array<ActionBarButton>();
    this.subscription = this.myService.actionBarShow$.subscribe(data => {
      this.setButtons(data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messages = this.myService.getMessages();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  setButtons(data) {
    this.buttons.push(this.createButton(data));
  }

  createButton(params?: IActionBarButton) {
    let button = new ActionBarButton();
    button.componentId = params.componentId || button.componentId;
    button.type = params.type || button.type;
    button.label = params.label || button.label;
    button.styleClass = params.styleClass || button.styleClass;
    button.func = params.func || button.func;
    return button;
  }

  doAction(button: IActionBarButton) {
    button.func();
  }
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your component code ?

Comment: @trichetriche , sure, coded added. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from here :

```
this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.routeConfig.data
```

You have indeed imported the router testing module, but don't expect it to be set up to your particular needs.

To avoid that, you can add a custom configuration in your `beforeEach` function :

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([] as Route[], {} as ExtraOptions);
```

Simply replace the parameters with values that are suiting your test case.

Comment: something like this `imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([] as Route[], {} as ExtraOptions)],` ? Doesn't seem to work. Does it require extra parameters?

Comment: @GeraldHughes exactly, and your routes should look like the ones of your component (for instance since you take the first child of the route, you should create at least one child on your mocked routes)

Comment: so [] should contain a PageViewModel with a id ( for this: this.router.routerState.root.firstChild.routeConfig
      .data as PageViewModel).Id ) ?

Comment: `[] → [{ path: 'PageViewModel', component: MyComponent, children: [...]}]`. Make a real route array; like the one you have in your module